# Azure SQL - DacPac Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dacpac

I am currently trying to test my DacPac deplyoment pipelines. However, I get error message all the time:

`##[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern C:\agent\_work\5\a\sqlproj_artifacts_1\DWH\DWH\bin\Release\database.dacpacCheck out how to troubleshoot failures at`

I can't find what the problem is. Here the code, idea why it does not work? Have done before and worked perfectly....

```
    steps:
      - task: VSBuild@1
        inputs:
          solution: '$(solution)'
          platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'sqlproj_artifacts_$(System.JobAttempt)'
          publishLocation: 'Container'
```

```
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'sqlproj_artifacts_$(System.JobAttempt)'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

```
        deployType: 'DacpacTask'
        DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
        DacpacFile: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/sqlproj_artifacts_$(System.JobAttempt)/DWH/DWH/bin/Release/$(azureSqlDBName).dacpac'
```

I'm using **AuthenticationType: 'server'**

And this is the local path where project is:
**source\repos\DataWarehouse\DWH\DWH**

Tried to adjust the path, but it still doesn't work.

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the path of the artifact you are looking for on the build screen when you click on artifacts:

[image]

Here the `$(azureSqlDBName).dacpac` file name looks suspicious to me, as in if the dacpac is produced from a sql project, then probably the file will have the project name, not the azure sql db name.

In addition to this, I also would try to publish separate build artifacts for separate deployment, so instead of creating an artifact for the whole source artifact directory, I would copy the dacpac from the source to staging directory and then publish the dacpac artifact:

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy DacPac Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*.dacpac'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/db'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/db'
    ArtifactName: 'sqlproj_artifacts_$(System.JobAttempt)'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Then it is easier to find what you are looking for when you need to use the artifact. Please note the `flattenFolders` flag which comes in handy when you are dealing with a single package within the artifact.

One more thing is the use of pipeline artifacts instead of build artifacts, since you are already working with yaml pipelines, and possibly multi-stage yamls, you can utilize pipeline artifacts which are automatically downloaded to the default workspace folder.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Why would you put the dacpac in source control? Doesn't that rely on developers to remember to build the project locally? Wouldn't it be more reliable to have your pipeline build the dacpac and copy that?

Comment: Absolutely... the dacpac file should be produced as a result of the compilation of the SQL project. Here the `CopyFiles` task is just copying it from the source directory since the `VSBuild` step in the question uses the source directory as path to publish.